# EventToCommand vs Behaviors in MVVM

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

When do you use the approach behaviors and when `EventToCommand`? I think, if the job to do is very specific, it is better to use `EventToCommand` and implement the work in the ViewModel. When the job can be reusable, than it's better to implement the functionality into a behavior.

**Updated**: 
For example, the function `DoPreviewKeyDown`:

```
        private void DoPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var view = (TableView)e.Source;
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(view.Grid.CurrentColumn, view.VisibleColumns[view.VisibleColumns.Count - 1]))
            {
                view.SearchControl.Focus();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            if (OkCommand != null)
                OkCommand.Execute(null);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if ((e.Key == Key.F) && (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control))
        {
            view.SearchControl.Focus();
        }
    }
```

I did that in my ViewModel. I can do that in a behavior but this functionality is very specific for this `grid`. That's why, I thought that is better to do it in my ViewModel.

Do you think this approach is valid?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. As such, I have voted to close your question. As a quick answer, I'd recommend using plain old Attached Properties to do what you want instead.

Comment: I can try to ask that with a specific example.

Comment: This site is really for specific programming problems, rather than asking for advice as your question is still doing.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to remove right now this post. Do you know and can you tell me where can I ask questions a bit more specific like that?

Comment: You really don't need other people's opinion on this matter... it's more about what suits *you* more... which method *you* feel more comfortable using. Just try out the different methods and see what works better for *you* personally. What I or anyone else prefers is neither here nor there when it comes to your code.

Comment: Define what your criteria for success is, create experiments with the scenarios you want to compare, and measure each against that criteria.  That will tell you what is best (or that they're equal) for what *you* deem important.

Comment: For me, I prefer to much as many view-related things in the XAML as a I can, whatever gets me that goal is what I normally try to do (depending on other constraints, but all other things being equal).

Comment: What I want to know is if there is a best practice or something "forbidden"  with this approach if I use the pattern MVVM. What I see is that I can not do this functionality in xaml code and a lot of code related to Grid,View,SearchControl and more specific controls of my view in the ViewModel is, from my point of View, not very clean. Otherwise, if I do that in a behavior,it won't be a lot reusable but it will avoid to write code in code behind.

Comment: It violates MVVM pattern to access Views and view related code in your ViewModels, so this approach is 100% wrong

Comment: That is a statement Tseng. Which is your approach in this case? Using Behavior? And when do you use EventToCommand?

Comment: And @Tseng I would say that EventToCommand violates 100% MVVM also, doesn't it?

Comment: It doesn't. EventToCommand is a pure View/Presentation Layer implementation and is reusable. It contains no business logic or presentation logic, it just delegates the event into a command. And your ViewModel has no idea that EventToCommand exists or which view calls it or even that a view exists.

Comment: Right, but you can pass the eventargs to the ViewModel and then you can violate very easy the pattern MVVM. In my opinion the ViewModel shouldn't never work with eventargs and through EventToCommand and the property PassEventArgsToCommand you can do that.

Comment: I never said you should pass EventArgs to the ViewModel. As far as I know, in MVVM Light#s EventToCommand you have to Parameters: `Command` and `CommandParameter` where you can pass whatever you want. However in that specific case, you may want to implement your own Behavior Action (like `KeyEventToCommand`), which reads the input key and pass it to the Command as a parameter, thus avoiding EventArgs in the ViewModel. And in ViewModel use event aggregator/messanging to send out loosely coupled events

Comment: On a side note: Above code looks more like View logic rather than presentation logic, which is more likely to fit into a UserControls code behind, since you seem to want to extend the TableView's functions rather than add "presentation logic"